# Where is previous Remote Desktop Connection session info stored in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I recently replaced my old Windows 7 machine with a new Windows 7 machine, and have my old drive mounted. If possible, I would like to access the list of "saved" machines from the drop down list in Remote Desktop Connection.

I don't remember the IP address of a machine that I need to remote to, and I know it would be in the list on that old drive.

Where would this list be stored on my old drive?

Answer (score 14):

It is stored in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`

Under sub-key Default you have a list of servers with values `MRUn=servername`

Under sub-key Servers you have keys for each `Servers` with values like `UsernameHint` or other custom settings for each server

You should be able to load your user hive from your backup and export the key then merge back into your current system. Make sure to unload the hive when done.

You'll probably need to modify the .reg file and make user it merges to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and not the location loaded imported the hive to.

For Information on loading a registry hive look here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157(v=ws.11).aspx. The hive you'll be looking for should be under `<systemdrive>:\Users\<username>\NTUSER.DAT`, this is an OS Protected file and you might need to uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" under Folder Options->View