# Machine Names pinned to Remote Desktop in Start Menu disappeared

Tags: remote-desktop, taskbar, start-menu, pinning

My Remote Desktop icon is pinned to the Start menu and I had 20 or 30 machine names pinned to it.  Sometime in the last week the list disappeared.  Anyone know if they can be recovered anywhere?

Comment: Were the individual machine names actually "Pinned" to the Start menu, or were they in the Remote Desktop Connection "Recent" list fly-out (the list you get when you click the arrow on a pinned RDP shortcut)?  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the "Recent" list fly-out for a pinned Start Menu shortcut, they are "automatic destinations" ([more info from MS here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511446.aspx#jump)).

They are stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`.

And have not-so-helpful names like `1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms`.

If yours went missing, you may be able to recover the files in that folder by using undelete or recovery software.  There's plenty out there to choose from and try.

Comment: This didn't work for me as there are no deleted files to recover under `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations.`

Comment: Mine have helpful and intuitive names but I can't remember how to create them and this doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Open the Remote Desktop connection dialog. In that drop down you can still find most of the recent connections (if not all) and hereafter manually restore your lost recent items by connecting again. Both host and user name is stored here.

I simply connected to all of them again and this time actually pinned them so I don't rely on the recent connections menu again.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/212335/503493) gives additional technical details on where to find the recent connection information from the connection dialog in registry, which may further inspire an automatic approach.

Comment: Correct - the first line didn't - I moved that to a comment. Better now?