# Backup Remote Desktop Connection (Windows) computer entries

Tags: windows-7, backup, remote-desktop

Is it possible to backup all entries saved in Remote Desktop Connection, which are shown next to the `Computer:` field?

I have around 15 entries and I am about to format my computer, and would like not having to re-enter them one by one and saving them.  I know you can do `Save As`, but still it takes some time to export 15 entries and re-import them.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Have tried using regedit and looked for say the ip address in order to find the registry key that handles this functionality?

Comment: @Ramhound I did a search, and found one similar under 'Terminal Services > Client'.  However, it does not seem to have the password, just the username and a 'Certificate Hash'.  I tried removing a node, and basically it re-asked for the confirmation that the SSL certificate is not valid, and whether I want to continue.  I've did an export of the whole node, and I will retry importing it when I do the re-install, and see if it works.

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://superuser.com/questions/212308/where-is-previous-remote-desktop-connection-session-info-stored-in-windows-7